# How to compact two relationship in one relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have some issue when I wanna compact two relationships in Laravel.
There were 3 tables with model.

```
table1: episodes --> model: Episode
      relations -- hasMany --> posts
               -- belongsToMany --> users

pivot-table2: posts    --> model: Post
      columns -- episode_id
              -- user_id
      relations  -- belongsTo --> user
                 -- belongsTo --> episode

table3: users    --> model: User
```

Yes, It was a many-to-many relationship. We could get posts or users relationships on Episode model.

If I have a single model collection

```
$episode = new App\Episode
```

How could it eager load like

```
$episodes = new App\Episode::with('posts.user').
```

Maybe I could do like below

```
$episode = new App\Episode::with('posts.user')->where('id','=','targetId')
```

But It seems like would first join three tables then make a query to get target episode.

Is there any way works like

```
 $episode = new App\Episode::find(targetId)-> with('posts.user')
```

Comment: Posts table should have user_id column in it.

Comment: @Ehs4n Sorry, It was my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using posts table just as pivot table, you are doing it wrong.

Episode Model:

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'posts');
}
// I would name my pivot table different than posts, if you don't pass the second parameter Laravel will look for episode_user table
```

User Model:

```
public function episodes()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Episode', 'posts');
}
```

In your controller:

```
$user = User::find(1);
$user->episodes();

$episodes = Episode::find(1);
$episodes->users();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @ Ionut Neculcea Thanks for your reply. I know these relationships but I just leave them out in my example. I wanna figure out how to eager load in a single `Post` model not `Posts` modelCollections.